# DICOM multiplanar image reconstruction

Tags: c#, image, dicom

My problem is, that I have to develop a program, that can open DICOM CT images in C# (without any library) and I should process the axial, coronal and sagittal images as well. I have figured these out, but the coronal and sagittal image reslution is not right. I checked out a million forums and questions, but I just didn't get the right way to find the coronal, sagittal resolutions. If someone can give me a formula or something I would be very happy.

As far as I saw these are the information needed to get the resoltion:

- Width and Height: 512x512
- Number of images: 518
- (0018, 0050) Slice Thickness: 1.25
- (0018, 0080) Spacing Between Slices: 0.625
- (0028, 0030) Pixel Spacing: 0.845703 / 0.845703

But I calculate the Spacing Between Slices from the (0020, 0032) Image Position (Patient), which is 0.625
And I don't really know what is the connection between these information, what is the formula to get the right resolution.
And my exact question is: What is the resolution of the coronal, and sagittal images?

If you guys need any more information about the slices just let me know.
Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:**
I checked with RadiAnt DICOM Viewer that the coronal/sagittal resolution should be 512x383. If anyone knows the formula why the result is 383. Please let me know. Meanwhile I'll try to figure out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to get a close solution. 1-2 pixels off from the RadiAnt version, but this is the best I could get:

Coronal image height/Sagittal image width: **number of images * spacing between slices / pixel spacing**

For example: 518 * 0.625 / 0.845703 = 382

RadiAnt image resolution: 512x383. My image resolution: 512x382

This solution works for some studies I tested with, but not for one or two from the internet. As **kritzel_sw** said it may vary. Hope this one will help a little for somebody else as well.

Comment: This does not seem to make sense to me. Why would one divide the resolution in the Z-direction (slice distance) divide by the resolution of the axial slices? They are completely unrelated. The height in pixels of a saggital/coronal slice is clearly 518 * 0.625.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but if I multiply 518 with 0.625, I will indeed get the Z-direction, but in mm, and I need it in pixels, so I have convert it to pixels. Distance between two slices is 0.625 and the distance between two pixels is 0.845703, so these can be used as ratio between mm and pixel (for measuring the distance). I just divide the 518 * 0.625 with 0.845703 and I get the Z-directions length in pixels. For me it makes sense, and I checked it with a program made for DICOM image priocessing and it strongly proves my idea.

Answer (score 2):

there is no clear answer for resolution. You should not forget that in DICOM you have the **PixelSpacing**, which you do not have in "normal images".

a typical image must always have a equidistant grid to be displayed correctly on screen. But in dicom you can have a image with 100x100 pixels and pixelspacing 1.0\1.0, and you can have a image with 100x200 pixels and pixelspacing 1.0\0.5. A valid DICOM-Viewer would display both images the same way. the second image has more pixels, but they are smaller. resulting in the same display as the first image.

So its obvious, that the height of the stack of images is 518*0,625 = 323,75 mm. So you have many possibilities:

- you could create a **512x324** image, set pixelspacing to **0.845703\1.0** and calculate (interpolate) the z-values.
- The best solution would be, to take the pixel data as they are, without any interpolation, so without any loss of data. Then you have a grid of **512x518** pixels. the pixelspacing would be **0.845703\0.625**. Thats because the spacing in x-direction comes from the spacing of pixels in the original data and the spacing in y-direction is the distance between the slices.
- But: there are some DICOM-Viewers out there who do not deal correctly with not-equidistant pixels. of if you export the image into jpegs and let window/browser display the image then you need equidistant pixels. Therefore you have to choose a number of pixels, so that in sum the heigh is 323,75mm when you have a pixel spacing of 0.845703mm. This are 323,75 / 0.845703 = 382,817 ~ 383 pixels. So if you generate a **512x383** pixel image, where you have to do interpolation of the slices, you can create a image with equidistant pixelspacing of **0.845703\0.845703**.

Comment: Yess!! I'm not crazy after all! I knew that this makes sense. Thank you for the professional explanation :) Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I assume:**

1. "Number of series": 518 should read "Number of *images*": 518?
2. Spacing between slices = length of the difference vector of Image Position Patient between two adjacent slices (value in DICOM header should be identical with calculated value. If not, I would recommend to use the calculated value).

**In this case:**

Resolution of saggital silces = Resolution of coronal slices = 512 slices, each with 512x518 pixels (Sagittal: height * number of slices, Coronal: width * number of slices)

Pixel Spacing saggital = pixel spacing coronal = 0.845703 * 0.625.

Slice distance sagittal = slice distance coronal = 0.845703 mm

*Side note:* Using a DICOM toolkit for reading the slices would be highly recommended. The fact that you can read this particular exam does not tell you that you are capable of reading *any* exam. There are many pitfalls in DICOM's low level encoding rules.

Comment: Yes, 518 is the number of images. I've tried the 512x518, but the image is streched, because the slices are overlapping (spacing between slices is less than the slice thickness). And what should I do with the 0.845703 * 0.625? If I multiply it with 518, the result is a quite compressed image. :/

Comment: If spacing between slices is less than slice thickness, the images are not optimal for 3D reconstruction. However, my formula is still correct - in 3D it is the position that counts. About the pixel spacing: it is asymmetric: x-direction: 0.84... y-direction: 0.625.